Derive gamma-parameters from preset R^2 in mixed models
For a simulation study in R, I want to select the effect sizes according to a preset $R^2$.
Consider this two level random intercept mixed model, with one L1 predictor $X_{ij}$ and one L2 predictor $M_{j}$:
$y_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{10} \cdot X_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}  $
$\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01} \cdot M_{j} + U_{0j}$
$\beta_{10} = \gamma_{10}  $
With:
$\epsilon \sim\  (N,\sigma^2)$ and
$U_{oj} \sim\  (N,\tau^2) $
As I understand there are mutiple definition of $R^2$ in the mixed model framework.
Following the approach of Snijders and Bosker, I understand that the $R^2$ for Level 1 is defined as:
$R^2_{1} = 1 - \frac{\sigma^2_{\text{model}} + \tau_{0,\text{model}}^2}{\sigma^2_{\text{null}} + \tau_{0,\text{null}}^2}$
The equation represents the proportion of variance explained at Level 1 (within-group variance and total variance combined), comparing the variances from the null model and the fitted model.
My goal is to fix the $R_{1}^2$ value to e.g. $R_{1}^2 = 0.3$, and derive the gamma-parameters from this.
However, I'm unsure on all the variance components. Anyone an idea on how to do this?
Snijders, T. A., & Bosker, R. J. (1994). Modeled variance in two-level models. Sociological methods & research, 22(3), 342-363.
